# extending jquery ui calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

is it possible to extend jquery ui calendar to have the following features.

1) i'd like to be able to create a url when the user clicks a day.

ie /mypage?date=15-03-2011  ( any date format is fine )

2) i would like the calendar to add class to each "a href" that represented a date. ie something like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1323518400000   datepick-weekend datepick-highlight" title="Select Saturday, Dec 10, 2011">10</a>
```

To put this context. i'm trying to use the calendar to display events that are held on a particular day.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) Jquery UI action out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onSelect callback to create an url, or add a class.

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        // Example"
        // '/route?date='+ encodeURIComponent(dateText)
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, onSelect seems to be called on page load as well as when a day is selected. Also do you know how to assign a class to each day. See point 2 above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by #2, are the links located somewhere else apart from the calendar on the page? or are you talking about the generated calendar UI control?

Comment: so each day in the calendar is separate td in a table. I'd like to be able to select days via a css class. td.date-15-03-2010 for example.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but you might be able to with the `.datepicker( "setDate" , date )` method. Once you have set a date datepicker sets a `ui-state-highlight` class on that anchor element. Otherwise, if this solution will not work for you, you will need to calculate and add the classes manually.